# KeyError: 'name'

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I am trying to login with facebook on my web application.
However, I keep getting this error message:

```
 return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args).
  File "/vagrant/itemcat2/application.py", 
  line 230, in fbconnect
  login_session['username'] = data["name"]
  KeyError: 'name'
```

Why does it say that the data name is a key error and it doesn't exist?
How can I fix it?

Below is the code the error message points to:

url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?access_token=%s&fields=name,id,email' % token

```
h = httplib2.Http()
result = h.request(url, 'GET')[1]

data = json.loads(result)
login_session['provider'] = 'facebook'
login_session['username'] = data["name"]
login_session['email'] = data["email"]
login_session['facebook_id'] = data["id"]

# Store token in login_session in order to logout
stored_token = token.split("=")[1]
login_session['access_token'] = stored_token
```

Comment: which api node are you trying to access?, it seems like the returned data doesn't contain 'name' as a key. perhaps you can try printing data out as a json string and examine the keys inside

Comment: facebook login api.

Comment: This has been solved, I could figure out that my token was not well split. The code below, solved the problem                                 
                                                                                                   
   **token = result.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].replace('"', '')**

Answer (score 1):

his has been solved, I could figure out that my token was not well split. The code below, solved the problem **token = result.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].replace('"', '')**